# Как изменить размер столбцов для QTableWidget (Qt Desinger)

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, qtablewidget, qheaderview

Как сделать так, чтобы *столбец 1* и *столбец 2* были к примеру по *40 пикселей* в длину и ширину *20*, а остальные растягивались для заполнения виджета?

Код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(610, 222)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 591, 201))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(100)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(25)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(25)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(25)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QHeaderView::**setSectionResizeMode**(int logicalIndex, QHeaderView::ResizeMode mode)
>
> Устанавливает ограничения на то, как можно изменить размер раздела, указанного с помощью `logicalIndex` в заголовке, до тех, которые описаны в данном режиме. Логический индекс должен существовать во время вызова этой функции.
>
> Эта функция была представлена ​​в Qt 5.0.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(610, 222)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 591, 201))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(100)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(25)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(25)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(25)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget) 

        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4) 
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)                                       

        self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) # !!!
      
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(20)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(40)

        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Fixed)  
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Fixed)         
       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]